# XLSX (Excel) underlying XML structure

Tags: swift, excel, ms-office

I'm writing a Swift application involving working with .xlsx files. I can unzip the files and view the contents of the underlying XML files, but I'm having trouble finding a thorough reference for understanding them.

[This article](http://professor-excel.com/xml-zip-excel-file-structure/) has been helpful for getting a sense of the general structure, but I'm looking for documentation on the XML tags and their meanings. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have previously implemented [a parser for XLSX](https://desiatov.com/swift-codable-xlsx/) in Swift and documented related XML nodes and attributes in the [`Worksheet`](https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/CoreXLSX/blob/master/Sources/CoreXLSX/Worksheet.swift) model file. In that model file I currently have self-descriptive property names assigned to almost all abbreviated attributes and nodes, hope that helps.